# Initialize a stack in C by setting pointer to NULL

Tags: c, null, initialization, linked-list

I'm trying to implement stack in C according to the following header (stack.h):

```
#ifndef STACK_H
#define STACK_H

/* An element from which stack is consisting */
typedef struct stack_node_ss {
  struct stack_node_ss *next;    /* pointer to next element in stack */
  void *value;                  /* value of this element */
} stack_node_s;

/* typedef so that stack user doesn't have to worry about the actual type of
 * parameter stack when using this stack implementation.
 */
typedef stack_node_s* stack_s;

/* Initializes a stack pointed by parameter stack. User calls this after he
 * has created a stack_t variable but before he uses the stack.
 */
void stack_init(stack_s *stack);

/* Pushes item to a stack pointed by parameter stack. Returns 0 if succesful,
 * -1 otherwise.
*/
int stack_push(void *p, stack_s *stack);

/* Pops item from a stack pointed by parameter stack. Returns pointer to
 * element removed from stack if succesful, null if there is an error or
 * the stack is empty.
 */
void *stack_pop(stack_s *stack);

#endif
```

However, being new with C, I'm stuck at the stack_init function, I have written in stack.c:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stack.h"

void stack_init(stack_s *stack) {
    (*stack)->value = NULL;
    (*stack)->next = NULL;
}
```

The main program begins with:

```
  int *tmp;
  stack_s stack;
  stack_init(&stack);
```

And this crashes my program with:

```
Program received signal EXC_BAD_ACCESS, Could not access memory.
Reason: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at address: 0x0000000000000008
0x0000000100000abf in stack_init (stack=0x7fff5fbffb30) at stack.c:6
6       (*stack)->value = NULL;
```

Can you hint me to the right track? Many thanks.

Comment: And this is why you don't hide pointer types behind typedefs unless there is a *really* good reason for it.

Comment: @Ed S.: exactly. Even `typedef struct{... } mystruct_t;` is questionable, IMHO. Why is this practice still taught in schools? Seems to me like the teachers all suffer a from terminal form of Pascalism.

Comment: @wildplasser: Well... when I write C I will `typedef` a struct to avoid writing `struct foo f;` everywhere.  I don't see that as problematic, but with pointer types... there be dragons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to allocate memory for `**stack` itself:

```
*stack = malloc(sizeof(**stack));
```

But please don't typedef pointer types. That's really confusing and hard to read. Better to pass the pointer by value and leave it to the caller to store the pointer, like this:

```
typedef struct stack_node_t
{
    struct stack_node_t * next;
    /* ... */
} stack_node;

stack_node * create_stack()
{
    stack_node * res = calloc(1, sizeof(stack_node));
    return res;
}

void destroy_stack(stack_node * s)
{
    if (!next) return;

    stack_node * next = s->next;
    free(s);
    destroy_stack(next);
}

// etc.
```

Then you can just say:

```
stack_node * s = create_stack();

// use s

destroy_stack(s);
s = NULL;  // some people like this
```

Comment: +1 for being correct *and* mentioning that it is generally a bad idea to `typdef` pointer types.

Comment: +1 for the explicit explanation! Now I have the stack working, but could you briefly explain the "s = NULL" after freeing memory for *s? would the value of s be undefined/something random depending on the system after "free(s)", if I don't write "s = NULL"?

Comment: And btw. the "s = NULL" turned out to be very useful indeed in my implementation, since I have to free the stack, if the user pops the stack until its empty (to avoid a leak in case the user quits the program), but I have to allocate memory again for stack, if the user continues to push to the stack again. So first, without "s = NULL", when stack becomes empty, I ran into a crash, when trying to check with "if(stack)" at the push-function, whether the stack has been emptied and memory has to be allocated again for stack.

Comment: You don't strictly need to set the pointer to null, but you may choose to use null as a sentinel value to indicate that no dynamic memory is currently held, and you could agree to a policy whereby a pointer is only non-null if it points to valid memory -- this may be useful if distant pieces of code need to be aware of the state of a pointer and be able to clean it up.

Answer (score 2):

You are dereferencing an uninitialised pointer, causing undefined behaviour.

Because this function is creating a new stack, you need to allocate some dynamic memory for the stack and then set the pointer to point to that newly allocated memory:

```
void stack_init(stack_s *stack) {
    *stack = malloc(sizeof(**stack)); // create memory for the stack

    (*stack)->value = NULL;
    (*stack)->next = NULL;
}

stack_s stack;
stack_init(&stack);
```

Then you should have a function called `stack_destroy` that will `free` the dynamic memory and set the pointer to `NULL`:

```
void stack_destroy(stack_s *stack) {
    free(*stack);
    *stack = NULL;
}
```

Comment: As long as it is always a `stack_node_s`.  Probably safer to use `sizeof(**stack)`

Comment: @EdS. you're right. My invalid pointer sense was tingling, but I forgot that `sizeof` is at compile time so it's fine

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize the stack to NULL - not to push a NULL value to it:

```
void stack_init(stack_s *stack) {
    *stack=NULL;
}
```

Comment: That is the most useless `init` function that I have ever seen... and it doesn't address the problem.  -1

Comment: @EdS. I know it's useless, but the OP wants a function... He tries to push NULL to invalid address, while there is not a reason to do this. all he needs is to assign NULL to the `stack_s` he got. (allocation is needed to push stuff)

Comment: No, he has an `init` function and one would expect that you would be able to use the stack afterward.  Your implementation simply guarantees that you will not be able to do so.  The OP's problem is that he didn't realize that the input to the function is expected to be a valid pointer to pointer to stack.  He declared a pointer to a stack (hidden through the typdef), but never initialized it.  If anything you should do the opposite; `malloc` the thing right then and there.

Comment: @EdS. Why doesn't it usable? to push a value, allocate space to it, put the value in it, make its next point to the current first member (which is `**stack`, not `(*stack)->next`), and make `*stack` point to it. Can you explain the line `(*stack)->value = NULL;` in Seth's answer?

Comment: `stack_s` is already a pointer, so `stack_s*` is a *pointer-to-pointer*.  That's why there are two dereferences.  This allows you to initialize the argument.  Your function sets the pointer to NULL... which now means it cannot be used.  I fail to see how that could ever be useful and there is no initialization going on.  If I call `init` I expect a valid object in return.

Comment: NULL is a valid value of pointers (you just shouldn't dereference it). My point (in the question at the end) was that there it doesn't make any sense to allocate a node (and initialize it) for an empty stack. (In the way I see it, `*stack` should point to the first node, not to a node that its `next` points to the first node)

Comment: Well every implementor of a stack type in history would likely disagree with you, but ok.